# Internal pull-up resistors not working

Tags: python3, raspberrypi

I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS on my RPi4 v1.1, and used this script:

```
from gpiozero import Button
import time
import os

stopButton = Button(26)

while True:
     if stopButton.is_pressed:
        time.sleep(1)
        if stopButton.is_pressed:
            os.system("shutdown now -h")
     time.sleep(1)
```

to safely shutdown the Pi using a pushbutton, only to find out it wouldn't work (is_pressed always returns true). The script worked on Raspberry Pi OS a few days before. After some troubleshooting, I found out that the internal pull-up resistor is not working, so the GPIO reads always LOW and no falling edge is ever detected. I already tried with GPIOs 26 and 17 (BCM numbering) and i2c module seems unloaded (using lsmod). Any ideas?

Additional info:
I tested my setup with Raspberry Pi OS twice and used a scope to determine that the GPIOs read LOW indeed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a RPi/RPi OS hardware or software issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue no longer exists if RPi.GPIO (and gpiozero) is installed via pip3. More details in my [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rpi.gpio/+bug/1899824).